# Very Specific Use Linux, Firefox, Ncomputing

Tags: server, firefox, virtualization

Okay, here's my situation. I need 5 "Kiosks" with the ability to access one specific website for people to do a survey. This is the only task the machines need to do.

I have an i3 computer (4gb ram) and 5 L300 ncomputing thin clients

I'm thinking that I want ubuntu server, firefox with enough gui to run it, and then install vspace to run the thin clients.

Any suggestions, alternatives, etc. will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oli made this once for Kiosk: http://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NoDM - this is a window manager that supports only 1 window. 
Start with server installation, then install `xorg nodm firefox`. That would be enough. 
Then create a separate user for kiosk, and in its home a file `.xsession`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
firefox
```

Run browser with `startx` command.